# Pandas dataframe .to_csv

Tags: pandas, export-to-csv

I'm trying to use `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv` to export a `DataFrame` to a `.csv` file, however after running the following code there's no output:

```
collist = sve2_all.columns
path_d = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\From EPD'
sve2_all.to_csv('sve2_all', path = path_d, columns = collist)
```

[Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: What if you leave out the `columns=collist` argument? (not necessary as you are writing all columns). Furthermore, the `path` kwarg is not in the docs you linked to.

Comment: What happens when you do the following: `sve2_all.to_csv(path_d + '\\sve2_all.csv')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are doing won't work as the path is not being used to set the destination path and resulting csv

This should work:

```
import os
path_d = 'C:\\Users\\Desktop\\From EPD'
sve2_all.to_csv(os.path.join(path_d, 'sve2_all.csv'))
```

Also, you are passing a string as the first parameter to `to_csv` which is probably confusing it also as it should be a fully qualified path or buffer  for `path_or_buf` parameter.

Comment: Indeed, `path` is not a kwarg of `to_csv` (but it apparantly does not give an error on this, but is just ignored)

Comment: @joris yes that is worrying, it would be nice that this raised an error but not sure how given python's flexibility